# Make div as high as its content (with position:relative)

Tags: css

I have a container with two things in it:

- A background that should be shown behind  and
- a list of elements on top of the background

I got the "behind" part working witz z-index and relative positioning. But now my container div doesn't resize its hight according to its content.  I want it to be as high as the list of elements inside it.   How can I do this without setting an absolute height in pixels?

```css
.container {
  width: 100px;
  height: 80px;  /* I want container to bis a high as its content */
  position: relative;
  border: 1px solid red;
}

.front,
.back {
  width: 100%;
  height: 80px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}

.back {
  z-index: 1;
}

.front {
  z-index: 2;
}

.inner {
  border: 1px solid green;
  margin-bottom: 4px
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="back">Background</div>
  <div class="front">
    <div class="inner">One</div>
    <div class="inner">Two</div>
    <div class="inner">Three</div>
    <div class="inner">Four</div>
    <div class="inner">Five</div>
    <div class="inner">Six</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

all you need to do is remove `height` from `.container` and `.back` and use `bottom: 0` for `.back`

also, you don't need `position: absolute` for `.front` so i removed it. because all the content is inside `.front` so it should be static or relative. so that the content takes proper height.

here is the updated snippet.

```css
.container {
  width: 100px;
  //height: 80px;  /* I want container to bis a high as its content */
  position: relative;
  border: 1px solid red;
}

.back {
  width: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
}

.back {
  z-index: -1;
}

.inner {
  border: 1px solid green;
  margin-bottom: 4px
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="back">Background</div>
  <div class="front">
    <div class="inner">One</div>
    <div class="inner">Two</div>
    <div class="inner">Three</div>
    <div class="inner">Four</div>
    <div class="inner">Five</div>
    <div class="inner">Six</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you very much for this great solution. Just if anyone else is stumbling over this:  Finally I actually changed to a table for doing the layout ...

Answer (score 0):

Try the following `css`: 
Remove height from `.container` and `.front .back`
And in `.front .back` change `position` to `relative`

```css
.container {   
  width: 100px;
  position: relative;
  border: 1px solid red;
}

.front,
.back {  
  width: 100%;             
  position: relative;  
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}

.back {
  z-index: 1;
}

.front {
  z-index: 2;
}

.inner {
  border: 1px solid green;
  margin-bottom: 4px
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="back">Background</div>
  <div class="front">
    <div class="inner">One</div>
    <div class="inner">Two</div>
    <div class="inner">Three</div>
    <div class="inner">Four</div>
    <div class="inner">Five</div>
    <div class="inner">Six</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just change the position to relative of `.front` and remove height.
height 100% on the `.back`

```css
.container {
  width: 100px;
  /*height: 80px;*/  /* I want container to bis a high as its content */
  position: relative;
  border: 1px solid red;
}

.front,
.back {
  width: 100%;
  /*height: 80px;*/
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}

.back {
  z-index: 1;
  height: 100%;
}

.front {
  z-index: 2;
  position: relative;
}

.inner {
  border: 1px solid green;
  margin-bottom: 4px
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="back"></div>
  <div class="front">
    <div class="inner">One</div>
    <div class="inner">Two</div>
    <div class="inner">Three</div>
    <div class="inner">Four</div>
    <div class="inner">Five</div>
    <div class="inner">Six</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this is the simplest code :

remove class front & back, change to just one class .content and .content::after.  put your background in content::after

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <title>test</title>
 <style type="text/css">
 .container {
   width: 100px;
   height: 100%;
   position: relative;
   border: 1px solid red;
 }

 .content {
   width: 100%;
   top: 0;
   left: 0;
   z-index: 0;
 }

 .content::after {
   background: blue;
   content: "";
   opacity: 0.9;
   position: absolute;
   top: 0;
   bottom: 0;
   right: 0;
   left: 0;
   z-index: -1;   
 }

 .inner {
   border: 1px solid green;
   margin-bottom: 4px
 }
 </style>
</head>
<body>
<div class="container">
  <div class="content">
    <div class="inner">One</div>
    <div class="inner">Two</div>
    <div class="inner" style="background: red">Three</div>
    <div class="inner">Four</div>
    <div class="inner">Five</div>
    <div class="inner">Six</div>
  </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: and you can add background in .content top to background .content::after like this : <div class="inner" style="background: red">Three</div>